# Sub routing best practices

Tags: rest, express, routes, backend, api-design

I am building an api which has a route: `/market/items/{category}`, it returns items from a category. If a user clicks on an item I have a route `/item/{id}/` which returns information about the item. I'm wondering if this is a bad practice when creating a restful api. because often I would see routes like `/market/items/{category}/{id}`. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only the `id` is needed in order to retrieve the item (in other words, the id by itself uniquely identifies the item without any other information), then there's no reason to require a category in the URL also so this:

```
/item/{id}/
```

would be just fine for a restful API.

If, on the other hand, there are multiple types of items, each with overlapping item identifiers, then you may need something else in the URL to uniquely identify which type of item and thus which pool of item identifiers to look in.

One reason you may see some web sites doing something like this in their web page URLs:

```
/market/items/{category}/{id}
```

is for search indexing where they want the category name to be associated with the item for purposes of search engine indexing.  But, if this is just a restful API, not visible web pages, then you probably aren't trying to optimize that for search hits.

Comment: Thank you! Is it normal for the client and server to have different routes, like in your example when the client url is `/market/items/{category}/{id}`, but the client does a get request to `/item/{id}/`?

Comment: @Nicke7117 - It's normal for HTML pages to have different URLs than API calls.  You design the API to make logical sense to a programmer (both the server developer building the API and the client developer using it).  You design web page URLs for the end user and SEO and for something that makes logical sense on the server-side.